# Or condition on ancestors in XPath?

Tags: xml, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I am trying to phrase a XPath which would look somewhat like this.

`//div[@class='foo']/ancestor::(fieldset or div)[@class='foo1']`

But XPath is not working at this point `(fieldset or div)`

A long XPath like the one below is working,

`(//div[@class='foo']/ancestor::fieldset[@class='foo1'] or //div[@class='foo']/ancestor::div[@class='foo1'])`

But, is there any concise way to build this XPath?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to select is:

- A fieldset or div
- With a @class value of `foo1`
- Which contains a descendant `div` with a @class value of `foo`

Taking this one at a time, we get:

A fieldset or div:

```
//*[self::fieldset or self::div]
```

With a @class value of `foo1`

```
//*[self::fieldset or self::div][@class = 'foo1']
```

Which contains a descendant `div` with a @class of `foo`:

```
//*[self::fieldset or self::div][@class = 'foo1'][.//div/@class = 'foo']
```

Comment: I'd forgotten a predicate, and I think you're right about OP wanting to select `foo1` elements rather than `foo` elements as my answer had.  Deleting mine and upvoting yours.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following xpath:

```
//div[@class='foo']/ancestor::[//fieldset or //div][@class='foo1']
```